# Calling a function from an object to another javascript file

Tags: javascript, function, file, linker

I have an object and lets call this object game.Door.
Inside this object I have a method.

```
openDoor: function() {
    game.removeRoom1();
    game.viewRoom3();
},
```

removeRoom1() is in this js file.
viewRoom3() is in another js file.

My HTML:

```
<script src="js/viewRoom3jsfile.js"> </script>
<script src="js/filewithObject.js"></script>
```

viewRoom3() is not working unless I put it in the same js file as my object.

Is there any way to have viewRoom3() in another js file?

---

Further clarification:

filewithObject.js:

```
var game = game || {};
game.Door = {
    openDoor: function() {
        game.removeRoom1();
        game.viewRoom3();
    },
};




game.removeRoom1 = function(){

}
```

---

```
viewRoom3jsfile.js:

game.viewRoom3 = function(){

}
```

---

Currently, my viewRoom3() is in the same file as my object and my javascript works.
However, if I move viewRoom3() into a seperate js file, the function stops working.

Comment: but you are calling the `viewRoom3()` of the object `game`.... So this function must exist inside your object.

Comment: Is `openDoor()` and `removeRoom1` in `filewithObject.js`?

Comment: Is openDoor() and removeRoom1 in filewithObject.js? - yes
and i want viewRoom3() to be inside viewRoom3jsfile.js

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it you have something like this:

```
var Game= {
    removeRoom1: function() { return something; },
    viewRoom3: function() { return something; }
}
```

So the function is inside the object. If you want the function to be in another js file other than the object, i suggest you do something like this:

```
var Game= {
    ....//object code here
}

//the following can go to another js file
function removeRoom1(obj) { return obj.something; }
function viewRoom3(obj) { return obj.something; }
```